# While fetching nearby places from google places api. Getting an error The provided API key is invalid

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api, swift4

I am trying to fetch nearby places but getting error The provided API key is invalid.

//From console.developers.google.com

I did create project from console developer enable the google places sdk for IOS and also generate API key and from Key restrictions i selected IOS Apps and provided my Key restrictions.

So my Question that is some thing wrong in my code or need to do some more setting stuff console.developers.google.com

func getNearByPlace(place: String) {

```
    var strGoogleApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=53.2734, -7.778320310000026&radius=50000&keyword=\(place)&sensor=true&key=\(googleApiKey) "
    strGoogleApi = strGoogleApi.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: strGoogleApi)!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            let jsonDict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)
            print("Json == \(jsonDict!)")
        } else {

        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove trailing blank space after `\(googleApiKey)` in your string. The blank space after API key breaks validation.

Also API key for Places API web service must be different from the API key that you used in Maps iOS SDK, because web services don't support iOS app restrictions. Web services can only be restricted by IP address of your backend server. That means you should mount an intermediate server that sends requests to Google and passes responses back to your application in order to protect your API key or use unprotected key if you call web service directly from application. The latter is a bad idea because it's a security flaw.

Have a look at the following article that explains a key system

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use your API_KEY in application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)

```
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")
```

And if you using Places API:

```
GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")
```

Just refer to public [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start?hl=ru)